# Regex add text after each match in a string javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have string containing different size images see below:

```
let newstr=‘assets/images/iphoneMoviesImg.png 1x,assets/images/iphoneMoviesImg@2x.png 2x,assets/images/iphoneMoviesImg@3x.png 3x’
```

What I can to do is prevent the images from caching in javascript.

I am trying to build a regex expression that can match to the image extension mime type and add a unique number after to prevent caching.
Below is a example of the result that I am after:

```
let newstr=‘assets/images/iphoneMoviesImg.png?3 1x,assets/images/iphoneMoviesImg@2x.png?3 2x,assets/images/iphoneMoviesImg@3x.png?3 3x’
```

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you only want regex solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use regex with `replace()` for this?

**UPDATE** OP wants to replace multiple mime types.

```js
let newstr='assets/images/iphoneMoviesImg.gif 1x,assets/images/iphoneMoviesImg@2x.png 2x,assets/images/iphoneMoviesImg@3x.jpg 3x';

var res = newstr.replace(/(png)/g, 'png?3');
 res = res.replace(/(jpg)/g, 'jpg?3');
 res = res.replace(/(gif)/g, 'gif?3');

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks @ProEvilz actually can would it be possible to also add in matches for .gif .jpg .png ?

Comment: @Dave Repeat the replace and swap png for which ever mime you need. Or you can match all in one go with `(png|jpg|gif)` but I'm not sure about how to map the correct mimetype with the match. If you use `(png|jpg|gif)` with the code above then all matches will become replaced with `png?3`